# How to put figure beside video (media9) in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, graphics, media9

Video:

```
\includemedia[
    activate=pageopen,
    width=5cm,height=5cm,
    addresource=videos/video.mp4,
    flashvars={
        source=videos/video.mp4 &
        autoPlay=true &
        loop=true
    }
]{}{VPlayer9.swf}
```

Figure:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{images/figure.jpg}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}
```

According to example code above, How can i put my video and figure beside each other (i mean two items in the same line) in Beamer?

Comment: Use the `columns` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way as one would put something else next to each other.

Thus, `\includemedia[...]{...}{...}\includegraphics{...}`.